# How do packages with multiple files work in golang?

Tags: go, package

[This](https://github.com/jcelliott/lumber) repo has 3 go files all begin with "package lumber".
To use this package, I'm supposed to put this in my `GOROOT` and simply

```
import lumber
```

in my program. How do variables and types in this package connect with each other across multiple files? How does the go compiler know which file to begin reading first?

In case I want to read the package, where should I begin reading to understand the package? What exactly is the flow of things here?

Comment: @elithrar: Not true. File scope and package scope are different scopes. For example, imports have only package scope, so catenating all source files of a package together doesn't work in the general case.

Comment: @jnml okay, so its basically like all the files are concatenated into a single large file, with the scope rules specified in the link you gave below, right?

Comment: @nomad: I don't think so. Import qualifiers are file scoped and that cannot be reproduced by joining the files into one. IOW, for example, the identifier `template` can refer to package 'text/template' in one file, but to package 'html/template' in other file. This scope cannot be "lifted" to the package scope.

Comment: Before doing anything in Go, everyone should have read: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you're not *"supposed to put this in my GOROOT"*. You're supposed to execute

```
$ go get github.com/jcelliott/lumber
```

which will clone the repository into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/jcelliott/lumber`. Then you can use the package by importing it in your code as

```
import "github.com/jcelliott/lumber"
```

About the scoping rules: [Declarations and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

Answer (score 23):

To elaborate on jnml's answer:

When you use `import "foo/bar"` in your code, you are not referring to the source files (which will be located in `$GOPATH/src/foo/bar/`).

Instead, you are referring to a compiled package file at `$GOPATH/pkg/$GOOS_$GOARCH/foo/bar.a`. When you build your own code, and the compiler finds that the `foo/bar` package has not yet been compiled (or is out of date), it will do this for you automatically.

It does this by collating* all the relevant source files in the `$GOPATH/src/foo/bar` directory and building them into a single `bar.a` file, which it installs in the pkg directory. Compilation then resumes with your own program.

This process is repeated for all imported packages, and packages imported by those as well, all the way down the dependency chain.

*) How the files are collated, depends on how the file itself is named and what kind of build tags are present inside it.

For a deeper understanding of how this works, refer to the [build docs](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).